# Excel Math using IFBLANK on certain cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that has some prices for parts, and then has a check list for those parts.

So basically I have in A column a list of budget leaps, such as 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 etc.  In B Column I have totals after subtracting the cost of items checked to the right of it.  So C would have brakes, D would have catalytic converter, E would have Access port.  I have a list of the prices of those parts on sheet 2 where in column A it has the Brakes, then Cat, then Accessport, in column b it has the associated prices such as 600, 300, and 1000.  So if I put in X in Sheet 1 row 1 next to the 100, it would subtract the price of brakes from 1000, if I also put an x under the cat it would subtract that price as well and leave it in the B column.  So if I have a row like this:

```
  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E
1000  ###   X     X
```

Then since I have C and D with X's it would subtract 600 and 300 from 1000 to leave 100 in column B.  But if I had this:

```
  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E
1000  ###         X
```

It would subtract only 300 from 1000 and leave 700 in column B.

Is this even possible?

So far I've tried

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1),A,B-Sheet2!A2)
```

Where A2 is where the price of the Brakes are and that does work.  But I don't know how to include D and E columns to that where I can x anything or everything and it all get subtracted from the total correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Use:

`=sum(A2,if(not(isblank(C2),-600,0)),if(not(isblank(D2),-300,0)),...)`

Replace the negative numbers with cell references as needed.

Actually, it shorter this way:

`=sum(A2,if(isblank(C2),0,-600),if(isblank(D2),0,-300),...)`

Comment: Worked great, except I changed it to =SUM(A2,IF(ISBLANK(C2),0,-600)  just to shorten it up a little.  Thanks!